# How to fit sequential operation on Spark Data Frame lineage when the operation limitation is that rows can only go in loop and not all at once?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, data-structures

I want to perform an operation or set of operations on data frame rows in chunks one after another after split.. loop is a possible solution but how to express a loop in terms of data frame operation

```
    DF:-
        Id  Cat Group
        1   A   G1
        2   C   G1
        3   B   G1
        4   A   G2
        5   C   G2
        6   B   G2
        7   A   G3
        8   B   G3
        
    DF:- STEP 1 --- SORT BY CAT GROUP BY GROUP
        Id  Cat Group
        1   A   G1
        3   B   G1
        2   C   G1
        4   A   G2
        6   B   G2
        5   C   G2
        7   A   G3
        8   B   G3
        
    DF:- STEP 2 --- SPLIT BASED ON CAT
    
    0   Id  Cat Group
        1   A   G1
        4   A   G2
        7   A   G3
        
    1   Id  Cat Group
        3   B   G1
        6   B   G2
        8   B   G3
    
    2   Id  Cat Group
        2   C   G1
        5   C   G2
        
    STEP 3 --- SEQUNTIAL LOOP ON SPLIT RESULT
    
    SPLIT[0] =>> MY_OPERATION
    SPLIT[1] =>> MY_OPERATION
    SPLIT[2] =>> MY_OPERATION
```

Please suggest a cleaner way to represent step 2- step 3 in terms of data frame operation itself so that all of that can be captured in the lineage.

Something like df.OrderedForEachUnique(cat).my_Operation()

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the *when* function in terms of :

```
df.withColumn('processed', when(Cat=='A', ...)
                          .when(Cat=='B', ...)
                          .otherwise()
)
```

Comment: Will it be possible to use "when" if I really don't know Cat values upfront??